# Reading environment variables under WildFly on Jelastic

Tags: jelastic

I have an app deployed to the WildFly application server on Jelastic. Even though I've set environment variables (following https://docs.jelastic.com/container-variables) my app can't read them. They show up as empty.

What I do I need to do to make it so that my app can read environment variables?

Comment: How do you read env vars in your app? Please also check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462069/passing-environment-variables-to-a-jvm-in-a-platform-independent-manner

Comment: @toby-one This issue was recognized as a product defect and will be fixed for new installations soon.
To get it fixed on your existing instance you should either wait until fix to be pushed to Dockerhub so that you can redeploy your node or you can [contact us directly](https://jelastic.com/contact/) to get fix as soon as possible.